# itfoxtec-identity-saml2 .NET Core MVC implementation, Is there any testdata we can test the implementation with?

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2, nemlogin, foxids

I’ve implemented your MitId login example for .NET Core MVC and I would really like to test the login.
Are there any test user-id’s that I can use to test with? I’ve tried a real person’s user-id but it’s not working..

I'm guessing the reason for that is because this is just a test environment and you obviously don’t have real user data there of course...

I've tried real data but that's not working understandably..

Answer (score 0):

You can only use test users in the test environment and real users in production.

How to create test users is described in the first section of the FoxIDs [connect NemLog-in](https://www.foxids.com/docs/up-party-howto-saml-2.0-nemlogin) documentation.